# Fast extraction of key-value pairs in Linux command-line

Tags: linux, bash, parsing

I have a large (tens of GBs) text file with data in `key=value;foo=bar;baz=quo` format.

The number and order of keys can change from line to line.

I need to process this file and extract values for the `foo` key, from Linux command-line (I'm using bash as a shell).

What is the most efficient way to do this without installing *huge* dependencies or writing code?

Comment: When handling files that big you might want too look into using another scripting language which handles files more efficiently. A fairly easy solution would be Perl (there are hundreds of examples online), or you could try (n)awk.

Comment: I actually meant bash as a cli shell, not as a scripting language. Fixed the question to reflect that. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

That's a lot of data, so just about any command line solution will be slow.

```
grep -oP '(?<=\bfoo=)[^;]+' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n -e 's/^foo=\([^;][^;]*\).*/\1/p'  -e 's/.*;foo=\([^;][^;]*\).*/\1/p' yourGBfile
```

-n option, don't print all lines

-e 'script'

The first -e script matches if a line starts with `foo=` 
and the second -e script matches a `foo=` following a semicolon.

`[^;]` means don't match any semicolons and `[^;][^;]*` means at least one non-semicolon (won't find empty values!), which effectively extracts your value between the equals and the semicolon.

The parentheses enclose a positional string which is referenced with `\1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try a perl solution, which might be faster:

`perl -nle 'print "$1" if /foo=(.*);/' filename.txt`

Comment: Your `.*` is too greedy. It won't work if there is more than one semicolon following the `foo` key (i.e. more than one other (key,value) pair following). And your match won't work if `foo` is the last key on the line (no `;` following). And you should add some anchor to make sure that only a `foo=` is matched and not `somefoo=` or `otherfoo=`. Suggestion: `print $1 if /(?:^|;)foo=([^;]*)/`.

Comment: Oh, yes, like in @glennjackman's code, instead of the explicit anchor, the word/non-word boundary `\b` comes in handy: `print $1 if /\bfoo=([^;]*)/`